# taskstats stats not adding up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process-accounting

I am trying to figure out how the stats in the taskstats struct are adding up. I wrote a simple C program that runs for some time doing IO and exits. I monitor the stats of this program using the taskstats struct, which I get from the taskstats netlink multicast group. When I sum the values of `cpu_delay_total`, `blkio_delay_total`, `swapin_delay_total`, `freepages_delay_total`, `ac_utime` and `ac_stime`, I get a value that is about 0.5 seconds larger than the value of elapsed time (`ac_etime`)

Here are the statistics for a 3.5-second run:

`ac_etime: 3536036`
`ac_utime: 172000`
`ac_stime: 3032000`
`cpu_delay_total: 792528445`
`blkio_delay_total: 46320128`
`swapin_delay_total: 0`
`freepages_delay_total: 0`

Summing up values for delays, utime and stime yields `4042848.573` (divide the delays by 1000 to convert to microseconds), while `etime` is only `3536036`!

Interestingly, the wall clock time gives the value that is practically equal to utime+stime: `cpu_run_real_total: 3204000129`, while `ac_utime + ac_stime: 3204000`

Does the `cpu_run_real_total` field give the cpu time, despite that the comment in taskstats.h clearly states that this is a wall clock time? And what could be the reason that the sum of these fields is larger than the elapsed time?

My kernel version is 3.2.0-38.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) cpu_run_real_total = ac_utime + ac_stime, I check the codes in ./kernel/delayacct.c, function __delayacct_add_tsk():

```
tmp = (s64)d->cpu_run_real_total;
cputime_to_timespec(tsk->utime + tsk->stime, &ts);
tmp += timespec_to_ns(&ts);
d->cpu_run_real_total = (tmp < (s64)d->cpu_run_real_total) ? 0 : tmp;
```

From the above codes, we know cpu_run_real_total is sum the utime and stime up.

(2) Why sum the values of cpu_delay_total, blkio_delay_total, swapin_delay_total, freepages_delay_total, ac_utime and ac_stime, the value is larger than the value of ac_etime?

I have not figured out why. But I have guess: the stime may somewhat overlap with the various *_delay_total counters.